# PHP throws an error... sometimes, on a DOM Element

Tags: php, dom

Somewhere in my code I have:

```
class aclass {
  ...
  function amethod() {
    $this->dom = $a_dom_document;
    $this->about = array('an_element' => $an_element_of_that_document);
  }
  ...
}

/* Somewhere else */

$instance->dom; // It's there, no problem.
$instance->about['an_element']->parentNode->replaceChild($something_else, $this->about['an_element']);
```

The code is complicated; I'm trying to only give the gist, here.

The strange thing is that it works about a quarter of the time. 3 out of 4 times, PHP says that replaceChild is a "Call to a member function replaceChild() on a non-object", but a quarter of the time, it actually works. What could be going on?

Edit: the following

```
print_r($instance->about['an_element']);
print_r($instance->about['an_element']->parentNode);
print method_exists($instance->about['an_element'], 'replaceChild')?'exists':'does not exist');
print_r($something_else);
```

returns:

```
DOMElement Object
(
)
DOMElement Object
(
)
exists
DOMElement Object
(
)
```

This is true even when the page fails.

I must be missing something very obvious. The $something_else is a node of the same DOM document.

SOLUTION: It was indeed very simple: for reasons I still don't quite understand, that part of the code is called twice. In one case, the instance is not defined, but that instance shows up in second place in the logs and I really was only looking for one. An if took care of it. Now I have to see why the #@!~ there are two of them in the first place.

Comment: generally this means that your DOM traversal didn't work.  In the example above it would mean that no parent node could be found for 'an_element'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print_r($instance->about['an_element']);
```

is not useful at all because the error is at the call to replaceChild. If $instance->about['an_element'] were null you would get the error that you're accessing a property (parentNode) on a non-object which you don't. 
Check that

```
print_r($instance->about['an_element']->parentNode);
```

is not null. I cannot say more without seeing the full code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's look at this logically.  It's saying that `call to a member function replaceChild() on a non-object`.  That means that you're trying to call `replaceChild` on something that either is not set, or is not an object (duh).  Let's look for where there's a call to replace child.

```
$instance->about['an_element']->parentNode->replaceChild(...)
```

So that means that `$instance->about['an_element']` must not have a parent node (otherwise it would be an object).  So that means it's either the root node or an orphaned node (A node that is still bound to the dom, but was already removed from the tree.  So it has no parent).  You can either add logic to prevent `an_element` from ever being non-parented, or you can check to make sure it has a parent before replacing:

```
if (is_object($instance->about['an_element']->parentNode)) {
    $instance->about['an_element']->parentNode->replaceChild(...);
} else {
    // You have a non-parented node, do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to debugging.

do `print_r($instance->about['an_element'])` and add that output to your answer.

I would suspect that no parent is being found for `$instance->about['an_element']`.

Comment: I can't format code here; I'll put it as an edit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

`insertBefore()` the current node then use `removeChild()` on the current node. you may occasionally be replacing a child node of a parent that doesn't exist.

Comment: This means that during traversal the DOM tree structure may have changed, i.e. the parent may have also experienced a replaceChild() which changes the structure, so the current node may not be a child of the alleged parent anymore.